# How to remove text from a line starting from the fourth tab to the end of the line?

Tags: python, parsing, tabs

I've just started programming, therefore I'm kinda noob.

I'm trying to use python to remove a column from a .txt table. All columns are separated by tabs.
This is an example line:

```
100226.SCO0401  1   440 COG0001 glutamate-1-semialdehyde 2,1-aminomutase
```

I want to remove all text in the line after the fourth tab (the "glutamate-1-semialdehyde 2,1-aminomutase" part).

I've seen some people importing csv to work around this issue, but I was thinking of something simple like:

```
def remove(infilename, outfilename):
    # Open original file and output file
    infile = open(infilename, 'rt')
    outfile = open(outfilename, 'wt')

    # Read lines and remove annotation
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line['**everything-until-the-fourth-tab**']

    # Close files
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

The bold part is my issue right now. Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.split('\t')` to split the entries in the row into an array. You can then slice the array with `[:4]`, keeping only the first 4 elements. Finally, join it back up again with `'\t'.join`:

```
for line in infile:
     columns = line.split('\t')
     columns = columns[:4]
     outfile.write('\t'.join(columns))
```

As a one-liner:

```
for line in infile:
     outfile.write('\t'.join(line.split('\t')[:4]))
```

Comment: Gonna try that ASAP. Can you just 'translate' the last line? The '\t'.join part. I got the (columns[:4]) one ^^'

Comment: @EdwardCoelho  `'\t'.join(columns)` is equivalent to `columns[0]+'\t'+columns[1]+'\t'+columns[2]+'\t'+columns[3]`

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I just added a \n at the end to keep the 'table look'

Answer (score 0):

I submit that using the `csv` module may be the simplest solution:

```
with open(infilename, 'rb') as infile, open(outfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        writer.writerow(row[:4])
```